# Accessing items inside a JSON [Using Typescript/Angular2]

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

What my JSON looks like:

```
{
  "reportSections": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "display": true,
      "nav": false,
      "reportGroups": {
        "reports": [
          {
            "name": "...",
            "url": "reportLibrary.tableau",
            "nav": true,
            "params": {
              "reportName": "clientRelationshipReport",
              "reportTitle": "Client Relationship Report",
              "reportUrl": "...",
              "reportHeight": "4030px"
            },
            "filters": "clientName,brokerName,entity,budgetClass,practice,office"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My HTML File template in the component

```
<li *ngFor = "let sectionName of reportNavJSONMain.reportSections">
     <span> {{ sectionName.name }} </span>
     <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let report of sectionName.reportGroups.reports">
          <a *ngIf="report.nav"> {{report.name}} </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
 </li>
```

What my component.ts method looks like:

```
//<irrelevant code> 
....
getReports(): any {
    new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      resolve(
        this.reportNavService.getJSONReportMain()
      )
    }).then((data)=>{
      // console.dir(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
      this.reportNavJSONMain = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.dir(this.reportNavJSONMain )
    })
  }
  ...
  //<irrelevant code>
```

My service code:

```
//.... 
public getJSONReportMain(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('...')
      .toPromise()
      .then((response: Response)=>{
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json()))
        this.reportNavJSON = JSON.stringify(response.json());
        return this.reportNavJSON;
      }).catch((error: Response)=>{
        return Observable.throw('Error');
      });
  }
  // ....
```

In component.ts file, I have initialized `this.reportNavJSONMain` as an object (I have also initialized it as an array of objects) but when I console.log() or console.dir() it, it always displays it as an "Object". I tried JSON.parse(), JSON.stringify(), and both but none of it worked.

My goal here is to access `reportSections` from `this.reportNavJSONMain` but when I do `this.reportNavJSONMain.reportSections`, reportSections is not part of this.reportNavJSONMain. However when I `console.dir(this.reportNavJSONMain)` or `console.log(this.reportNavJSONMain)`, it displays this:

```
{"reportSections":[
     {"name":"...","display":true,"nav":true,"reportGroups":
          {"reports":
              [{"name":"Client Relationship Report","url": .....}
```

Comment: Can you please improve the formatting

Comment: @Zze, yes I can, what's the proper formatting to make it look more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't navigate / iterate a string, but you can an object!

(I assume `this.reportNavJSONMain` was declared either as a `var` or `Object`)

If data is of type `Object`

```
).then((data)=>{
    this.reportNavJSONMain = data;
})
```

If data is of type `String`

```
).then((data)=>{
    this.reportNavJSONMain = JSON.parse(data);
})
```

---

An example of how to implement this in Javascript,

```js
var object = {
  "reportSections": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "display": true,
      "nav": false,
      "reportGroups": {
        "reports": [
          {
            "name": "...",
            "url": "reportLibrary.tableau",
            "nav": true,
            "params": {
              "reportName": "clientRelationshipReport",
              "reportTitle": "Client Relationship Report",
              "reportUrl": "...",
              "reportHeight": "4030px"
            },
            "filters": "clientName,brokerName,entity,budgetClass,practice,office"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(object);
});

p.then((data) => {
  data.reportSections.forEach((section) => {
    console.log(section.reportGroups);
  })
});
```

Comment: I don't think this.reportNavJSONMain is a string? The console would have displayed quotations marks around the object

Comment: @ezzzCash This is the code you posted: `this.reportNavJSONMain = JSON.stringify(data);` that converts an object to a string. Did you want `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: When I do JSON.parse(), it displays "Object" on the console with the attributes of the JSON underneath. However, I still can't access reportSections

Comment: okay so I initialized it as `.then((data: Object)=>{
      this.reportNavJSONMain = data;
      console.dir(this.reportNavJSONMain.reportSections);
      console.dir(this.reportNavJSONMain);
    })`  but  `this.reportNavJSONMain.reportSections` is now 'undefined' on the console (which was my original problem)

Comment: @ezzzCash I've added a javascript snippet which mimics the correct functionality - hope this clarifies my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're turning your JSON result into a string with JSON.stringify(), on your http result you want to call result.json() in your service. This way you emmediately have the result as json.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to show you the code in my service, I'm already doing that. I will edit my question to add my code in service

Comment: In your service you are also returning a string, just return response.json() from service and put that in the reportNavJSONMain property in your component.